# Truth for an empty array

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Why does an empty array evaluate as false:

```
[]==false//true
```

and anded with 1 equals true :

```
[]&&1==true//true
```

and reversed with 1 equals false:

```
1&&[]==false//true
```

What looks really weird:

```
[]&&5==false//true
```

Comment: @JeremyBanks Im sorry but I did not ask for your advice, I need an explaination, if you cant explain, please dont downvote my question.Thank you

Comment: just curious, how did you figure this out?

Comment: Because the `==` operator is insane, and has semantics that nobody should ever learn because it would encourage them to use it instead of something reasonable like `===`.

Comment: @JeremyBanks "== operator is insane" doesn't sound like an answer from someone who understands Javascript

Comment: It's the logic of this language.
Nothing means false.
But, if you use === instead of ==, for sure, it's not false

Comment: @JeremyBanks the duplicate question makes more sense, Thank You.

Comment: What I don't understand is how #2 and #4 have the same output. How is `1==true` true, and `5==false` also true? I thought only `0` was falsy?

Comment: @user1136560 `[]&&1==true` is `[] && (1==true)`, not `([]&&1) == true`.

Comment: I don't get `true` for #4. `[]&&5==false` → `false`

Comment: You messed up the 4th expression's evaluation. [It's actually false.](https://jsfiddle.net/r4kvhfwp/)

Comment: @4castle both are false !! https://jsfiddle.net/r4kvhfwp/2/, it equals 5 !

Answer (score -1):

`&&` returns the left-hand side if it is falsy, otherwise it returns the right-hand side

`true` is 'equal' to `1`

`false` is 'equal' to `0`

`[]` is not 'equal' to `true` or `false`

`[]` is a truthy value

`==` has higher precedence than `&&` (is executed first),

so:

`[]&&1==true` => `[] && true` => `true`

`1&&[]==false` => `[] && true` => `true`

`[]&&5==false` => `[] && true` => `true`

Comment: `[]&&1==true` is `[] && (1==true)`, not `([]&&1) == true`.